# PHP SOAP Server method receive a set of parameters

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, zend-soap

I have setup a SOAP Server with php.

The problem is that, as per the WSDL, the client which calls the server method, is supposed to pass a set of parameters (more than 50). I got to know this from SOAP UI.

But how do i handle all those parameters in my Server method?
Should i go on and declare each and every parameter for my Server method, as below?

```
public function addMessage($a, $b, $c, $d, .................) {

}
```

But I hope there must be a simpler approach to this. Preferably, i would like to receive all parameters in my Server method, as an array or object.

**UPDATE**: I am using Zend_Soap_Server. Do i need to define any complex types, for handling input parameters? As i see, the WSDL defines few complex types.

Comment: Define your own ComplexType with these parameters as properties and make this method accept only one argument of this object.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Well, i saw that the WSDL is using some XSD files that define the complex types with several parameters. Hope i can pass these complex type objects as parameters to my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i could finally receive the parameters as objects in my method. These objects were already defined as complex types in the XSD files.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

```
public function addMessage() {
    $args = func_get_args();

    foreach($args as $argument)
    {
         # processing 
         $this->do_process($argument);
    }
    var_dump($args);
}
```

Call

```
$this->addMessage('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ....);
```

and function will return

```
array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c', 4 => 'd' ....);
```

Comment: But as i mentioned, it is the Client who is calling my SOAP Server method. So i am not sure how he will pass arguments to my method. I am supposed to define the arguments for my method and process them.

Comment: As you have said: "i would like to receive all parameters in my Server method, as an array or object." - method func_get_args() gets  incoming parameters as array. After that you may to process them as you like

Comment: But without even defining any arguments to my method, is it possible to get all the incoming parameters?

Comment: If I understand the last question, this function gets all yours incoming parameters. I'm add example