# Auto load paramaters in SOAPUI

Tags: soapui, soapserver

When using soapui , sometime it autoloads parameters of soapserver when not passing any variable to soapserver. The parameters will be displayed in left window

I've created a soapserver in PHP, it runs well, but I can not make soapui load my parameters like that. How can I do that? Thank you very much

Comment: @shasi-kanth : i found your previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783629/php-soap-server-method-receive-a-set-of-parameters
I think it is the same issue as I get but I don't understand your solution. I am very appreciated if you can show more detail. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new project in SOAP UI and initialize it with your web service WSDL. See [steps](http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html) in the official documentation.

If your SOAP service operates in non-WSDL mode, then there is just no meta information which can be used to generate request templates in SOAP UI.

Comment: thank you. however my SOAP service do operate in WSDL mode, It works with all request and return meta data. I wonder how to generate xml template so that Soapui can understand it is for parameter?

Comment: I suppose by "xml template" you mean WSDL? As I understand from your answer, you just had malformed WSDL and was not able to generate payload template in SOAP UI, correct?

Comment: yes, something like that. I use a function to read class file and generate WSDL for each funtions in the class. With some functions' WSDL, SOAP UI can not understand payload template. I can not find out why. So with these cases, I create outsite WSDL file instead of using automatic code

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can make it happened :) the issue is that there is error somewhere in my xml code but I can not find out. So I use the wsdl from here: http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl
 and replace my code into it. It works.